# Sympy: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Symbol'

Tags: python, sympy

Hey so I'm making a school project which plots the graph of two linear equations and shows its solution.

Could not find helpful information online and as I'm new to python, am not sure where the problem lies and how to fix it

**Error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Symbol'**

If I then try to manually convert said *error* to integer using **`int()`** function I get a new error

**Error: TypeError: can't convert symbols to int**

[Full Code](https://pastebin.com/TbbuMC3c) : (as its too long am adding a link to a pastebin)

I think the error lies here:

```
def solve_eq(a1 , b1 , c1 , a2 , b2 , c2):
    x = simp.Symbol('x')
    y = simp.Symbol('y')
    eq = (a1 * x + b1 * y + c1 , a2 * x + b2 * y + c2)
    global sol
    sol = simp.solve(eq , x , y)
    print(sol)
    m = re.match(r'^{x: (\d+), y: (\d+)' , str(sol))
    if m:
        return m.group(1) , m.group(2)
```

**Full TraceBack Error:**
Traceback (most recent call last):

line 117, in 
run()

line 115, in run
plot()

line 102, in plot
solx , soly = solve_eq(a1 , b1 , c1 , a2 , b2 , c2)

line 85, in solve_eq
eq = (a1 * x + b1 * y + c1 , a2 * x + b2 * y + c2)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Symbol'

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks a lot for your time!

[Adding a link to the youtube video that Im referring to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIT_JyvhUlU&t=1274s)

Comment: A `sequence` is a python object such as a list or string.  `alist * 3` is defined as replicating the list 3 times.  Obviously that kind of replication is not defined for a `float` or, in your case a `sympy` `symbol`.  What are those arguments lie `a1`, `b1`, etc?

Comment: When you ask about an error, show the full error with traceback.  We don't like to guess where things are happening. Where did you use the `int`?   We don't need to see the full code, but we do need to see the error and information about the variables that are involved.  In other words, real debugging informaiton!

Comment: The problem seems to be that `a1` etc. come from `input()` and thus are of type string. You need to explicitly convert them to a number, for example using `a1 = sympy.sympify(a1)`. Using `sympify` helps to make sure that an integer won't get mispresented as a float. Moreover, `sympify` allows expressions such as `1/2` to be converted to fractions instead of floats.

Comment: oh im sorry im new to asking questions in stackoverflow ill just edit my post with the full traceback

Comment: IT WORKED!!! i used the sympify function but am getting a new error ;-; thanks a lot tho

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, SymPy is a bit unstable. I've got the same error message while I was working in Jupyter Lab, and it persisted until I re-executed the cell with the `import` statement.
Try to insert `import sympy as simp` right after `def solve_eq(...):`